# How to send image attachment to server in post data iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Send data to server works in postman but getting error in Objective-C.

[image: image1]

I tried to achieve this one failed from server. I referred below links does not work. Getting error upload failed. What am I doing wrong?

[Upload image to server ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074429/upload-image-to-server-ios)

[how to POST value while uploading image in iOS objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487426/how-to-post-value-while-uploading-image-in-ios-objective-c)

My Code:

```
NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 1.0f);

// set your URL Where to Upload Image
NSString *urlString = @"http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/index.php/API/uploadClaim";

NSDictionary *user = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userDetails"];

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.

NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[_params setObject:@"filename"  forKey:@"file_name"];
[_params setObject:@"photo"  forKey:@"file_type"];
[_params setObject:[[user objectForKey:@"user_data"] objectForKey:@"id"]  forKey:@"user_id"];

NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";
NSString* FileParamConstant = @"image";

NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

// create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:120];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params)
{
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// add image data
if (dataImage) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:dataImage];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
// set URL
[request setURL:requestURL];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *requestError = nil;

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&requestError];
```

Comment: I tried with AFNetworking also does not work.

Comment: Look at your requestError after sendSynchronousRequest and see what it says.  Also, you should not be using sendSynchronousRequest anymore -- use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:]

Comment: Given the http scheme, probably missing TLS setup.

Comment: "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" the LFCR thing at the end doesn't seem right to me. idk.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872888/image-upload-using-afmultipartformdata-afnetworking-3-0 --> Solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

Here is my working code to upload one or multiple image files:

Please note:  you should pass images/files data in an NSDictionary with proper key values & You should set key name as your server expecting in upload call.
For example in your case it is `file`

`parameters` dictionary will be your other parameters to send with `file`

```
- (void) performNetworkEventRequestCallWithFileUpload :(NSMutableDictionary*) imagesData : (NSMutableDictionary*)parameters completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, NSDictionary *dict))completionBlock {


NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[urlRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[urlRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


[parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(NSString *key, NSString *object, BOOL *stop) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}];


[imagesData enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(NSString *key, NSData *object, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
        if (object.length > 0) {
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            NSString *timeSTamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",key,timeSTamp] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:object]];
        }

    }
}];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:body];


AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = nil;

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        completionBlock (NO, responseObject);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"success");
        completionBlock (YES, responseObject);
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i am using Afnetworking for Uplaoding image us Multipart format, its working fine. So, check it. If its ok for you just vote my answer.

```
#import "AFHTTPSessionManager.h"

{ 
  NSData * profileData;
}


   profileData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 1.0);

-(void)UploadImageApi
  {

   NSString *URLString = @“YourURL”;
   /*Profile data is nothing your pick image from gallery or Camera, That saving in profile data.*/

NSMutableDictionary *parameter=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[parameter setObject:@“yourObj” forKey:@“YourKey”];
[parameter setObject:@“yourObj” forKey:@“YourKey”];

[parameter setObject:@“yourObj” forKey:@“YourKey”];


if(profileData==nil)
{
    [parameter setObject:@"" forKey:@“YourKey”];

}


AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer
                              serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[manager POST:URLString parameters:parameter constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

    if(profileData!=nil)
    {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:profileData  name:@“YourKeyName” fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }

} 
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

          NSMutableArray *json = [responseObject mutableCopy];
                        NSLog(@" success = %@",json);


 } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
     NSLog(@"%@",error);

 }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use much simpler approach for data as well as for image:

```
NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449",
                           @"cache-control": @"no-cache" };
NSMutableArray *parameters = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"param1",@"param2", nil];
NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"value1",@"value2", nil];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
//NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0f); uncomment for image

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

for (int i=0;i<parameters.count;i++) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",[parameters objectAtIndex:i]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[values objectAtIndex:i]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
NSLog(@"Parameters : %@",parameters);
NSLog(@"Values : %@",values);

//image 
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"file.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:dataImage]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://your API URL here"]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                 if (error) {
                     NSLog(@"%@", error);
                 } else {
                     NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                     rowBtnTableLast2=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
                     NSLog(@"PostMethod Result : %@, PostMethod Error : %@",array,error);
                 }}];
[dataTask resume];
```